# Highcharts dynamic height with table layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

Is it possible for the height of the charts in the following code snippet to resize automatically in the same way as the width does (see jsfiddle below)?

```
<div class="chartTable">
    <div class="chartRow">
        <div id="chart1" class="leftContainer"></div>
        <div id="chart2" class="rightContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="chartRow">
        <div id="chart3" class="leftContainer"></div>
        <div id="chart4" class="rightContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmoowwm1/

Commenting back in the "position:absolute" styles will illustrate how I would like it to work, but obviously need all 4 graphs in view.

Comment: You can catch $(window).resize() event and then call [chart.setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize) with calculated width/height.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to achieve my desired behaviour using CSS alone rather than manipulating the charts, which should be responsive by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use CSS, you need keep the first row **`position:absolute`**.

I used **`position:fixed`** for the second row and **`bottom: 0`** to keep it bottom as a footer. So this will only work for a two row chart page. Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cmoowwm1/5/)** of what you are looking for.

Comment: So are you saying that because of the absolute and fixed positioning, this would NOT work if this screen was being generated dynamically in which case multiple "two chart" rows could be created?

Comment: I didn't fully get what you mean by that sentence, but what I meant was that you can have a dynamically generated page with two rows of charts (as many as you can put in a row). For more that two, my way doesn't work because of the **`position: fixed`**. You cannot use **`position: absolute`** for every row because they will overlap and cover one another.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I meant. I need to generate multiple rows. I have since solved this problem using javascript in my own application, but I think because I didn't mention this requirement in my question, your answer is a perfectly acceptable solution.